# Windows 8 and AMD's Catalyst Control Center 13.1: Crossfire Missing?

Tags: windows-8, drivers, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, amd-radeon

I have two ATI Radeon HD 4XXX series video cards on my machine ([card 1](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814150359) and [card 2](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814103194)), and I'm running Windows 8 [Version 6.2 (Build 9200)]. I normally run with crossfire *disabled*, as I have three monitors + a TV hooked into both video cards (leaving a total of four monitors displayed). Earlier this evening, Windows froze, so I hard-reset it. When it came back up, it began installing updates, and when all was said and done, the second video card appeared offline (two blank monitors).

CCC / Windows could not see the other two monitors anymore, and it looked like Windows had tried to install a later driver for the ATI cards, but failed? (Windows Update claims the last updates occurred yesterday, which was untrue). I was running on an older version of CCC (don't remember how old, but it was for Windows 7). However, there seems to be a "stable" Windows 8 version of CCC now (13.1). Despite these claims, though, the "Enable/Disable" crossfire option is no longer available.

I could not find my solution online, and have tried completely uninstalling/reinstalling AMD/ATI software/drivers many times, with restarts, etc. to no avail. The most I can get out of CCC is (note that the 'Gaming' and 'Performance' tabs are missing the 'Crossfire' option):

[image: AMD CCC]

This is incredibly frustrating, of course, and would like to resolve the matter as quickly as possible. *Unlike issues others have with this, I am not missing the majority of options in CCC. The only option I'm missing is Crossfire.*

The version of CCC I'm using is 13.1, which I downloaded [here](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/windows/Pages/radeonaiw_vista64.aspx).

Thank you for your time.

EDIT: Updated CCC screenshot to show all tabs expanded.

EDiIT 2: Curious, I checked the Software Update under the About section, and found that it's rather blank:

[image: CCC Sofrtware Update]

When I click "Check for updates now...":
[image: CCC 'Check for Updates' window]

No idea if this is related to my current problem or not, but more information for the masses to chew on.

Comment: In my CCC, I have Crossfire available in the performance tab as well. I hope this is not a stupid question, but did you check there?

Comment: Not a stupid question at all! ^_^ It's not there either, and I updated the image to have all the items expanded for clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When all else fails, rip things out.

After many more failures, I decided to see if the hardware was all still good. I hadn't touched the machine prior to this happening, so I figured that couldn't be the case.

Turns out... it wasn't the case!

I removed the physical bridge between the two video cards, and now CCC shows the Crossfire option:

[image: Crossfire]

It correctly warns that Crossfire can't be turned on since the bridge is missing, so it forces itself to turn off, and voila! Two separate video cards again. I believe this issue lies in the fact that CCC doesn't handle the Crossfire case correctly (i.e. it turns it on by default), and spazzes for some other reason.